# Master-Slave JK Flip Flop Truth Table

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, flipflop

In my computer logic and design class, we have gone over the different types of flip flops and their representations. I understand what the goal of the master-slave configuration is but I am having trouble figuring out how it works.

**Given the JK Flip Flop Below:**

[image]

Let the current state of the flip be **[CLK = 0, J = 0, K = 1, P = 1, Q = 0]**, This would make both **S1** and **R1** equal to **0**, resulting in **P = 1**. But **J = 0, K = 1** should be a reset operation. Doesn't this contradict what a JK flip flop is supposed to do? Are there methods to prevent this from happening?

Comment: please add a link to the source of the logic diagram into your question

Comment: find a diagram that is all discrete gates ... it may help you to understand the signal flow

Comment: Gates should not be "nand" gates ...

Comment: @Antonio51 Which NAND gates?

Comment: Where did you obtain this circuit, or did you invent it yourself? It seems to be wrong, as it exhibits strange behaviour, for example outputting a 1-cycle `1` when starting from the described situation. (Please note that this is not a forum, [edit] your question to clarify.)

Comment: @thebusybee Are the RS made with NAND gates or NOR gates?

Comment: @Antonio51 I have no idea, you need to ask the OP. However, it is shown as a black box, and I think most of us assume the "academic" behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

As long as **S1 = 0** and **R1 = 0**, the first flip flop will keep its state.

Your comment:

> What would happen though if while in the LOW clock signal a J=1, K = 0 signal is sent, setting P to 1, then a J=0,K=1 signal is sent. That would create the situation I described, correct?

Correct, but this does not contradict the definition. By the sequence you describe you set the first flip flop (intermediate **S1 = 1** and **R1 = 0**), but because of **Q = 0**, the **K = 1** never gets to the flip flop, always **R1 = 0**.

Answer (score 0):

No, in a JK flip flop, on a rising clock edge, J=0 K=0 results in Q<sub>n+1</sub>=Q<sub>n</sub> and J=0 K=1 results in Q<sub>n+1</sub> =0

J=0, K=1 is the reset
J=0, K=0 maintains the output.

<strike>In your example above, your conditions are invalid. If Q<sub>n</sub> = 0, then P<sub>n-1</sub> = 0 and P'<sub>n-1</sub> = X. A value of P=1 will produce Q=1 when the clock edge appears.</strike> 

Ok so for the conditions Q<sub>n</sub>=0, and therefore P<sub>n</sub>=0, then we apply CLK<sub>n+1</sub> = 0, J<sub>n+1</sub>=1, K<sub>n+1</sub>=0, S<sub>1</sub> = Q' & J & CLK' = 0, setting P<sub>n+1</sub> = 1. While Q = 0, R<sub>1</sub> = 0, so the SR flip flop cannot be reset. 
When we apply CLK<sub>n+2</sub> = 0, J<sub>n+2</sub> = 0, K<sub>n+2</sub> = 1, P<sub>n+2</sub>=1 still because the flip flop cannot be reset until it rises high. When the next CLK edge appears, Q = 1

This transition of changing J and K inbetween I think is invalid, and hence why it produces this unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, that first part was a typo, J=0, K=1 is the reset. What would happen though if while in the LOW clock signal a J=1, K = 0 signal is sent, setting P to 1, then a J=0,K=1 signal is sent. That would create the situation I described, correct?

Comment: See my edit, I understand your point now